# Unity - Logic to pick up objects and drop them one by one at different positions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Please look at example - http://www.mathplayground.com/mancala.html
Can anyone suggest the logic to :
1) spawn objects at positions 
2) Pick up all objects on click and distribute them one by one.
3) Is it better to create all objects or instantiate them on the fly. ?

I tried code below but it just instantiates all objects at once.

```
            if (HoleHandler.gemCount_Hole1_Update_Flag == true)
        {

            foreach (GameObject g in gemList1)
            {
                Destroy(g);
                //want to add a time delay of 2 secs here
            }

            if (gemCount_Hole1 > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < gemCount_Hole1; i++)
                {
                    int Gem_prefabIndex = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 9);
                    gemList1.Add(Instantiate(Gem_prefabList[Gem_prefabIndex], new Vector2((xPos_Hole1 + (Random.Range(-20, 20))) * 2.0F, (-229 + (20 * i))), Quaternion.identity));

                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure of what you're trying to achieve but I will answer as best I can.

For a start, any gameobject you are going to be instantiating (spawning) at run time should ideally be done so from a prefab.

Secondly, to spawn them at random intervals you want to be checking if they should be spawned at different time frames. This can be achieved through a co-routine or the Update function. I would recommend Update if this is new to you.

Update is called every frame.. and it's with this that you can achieve timed events. You can use a variety of helper methods to determine the time since the last frame or the real time elapsed.

For example

```
public class MyGameObject : Monobehaviour {
    void Start() {
        //This is called first, use it to set up whatever you want.
    }

    void Update() {
        //This will be called every frame.
        //Each frame or time lapse will determine if I should spawn
        // a new gameobject.
    }
}
```

**Update**

After looking at the game you have linked in your post I can offer the following advice.

Something like the following may point you in the right direction.

```
public int[] gemsInCups = new int [] {4,4,4,4,4,4,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,0};

public void Distribute(int position){
    int gems = gemsInCups[position];

    for(int i = position + 1; gems > 0; i++){
        gemsInCups[position] ++;
        gems --;

        //Check the end of the array has not been reached.
        //If it has, start distributing again from the first position provided 
        // there are still gems to distribute.
    }
}
```

You will need some additional logic to finish this.
What you should remember is, I usually find it much more manageable keeping my data and my view (gameobjects) under different scopes... but the view will change to reflect the data and does not directly alter it. Now you know how many gems there are in each cup, you can simply update this each frame.

Comment: Thanks.You say you are not 100% sure of what Im trying to achieve. Did you get a chance to look at the link I have in my question - That will make it clear.

Comment: I know what update and start does. I also have the game coded but right now I destroy all gems and instantiate them again instead of moving them like the example i attached. So I dont know if I need to create 48 prefabs for 48 gems or if I can continue with my logic of 1 prefab and instantiate it as needed. Im a beginner to unity so any logic on how to do this will be appreciated. But please check the link in my question

Comment: very helpful. Gives me a good start to redesigning my game. Thanks for your time.